# TCL - obtain the list of strings separated by white space in another string using regular expressions

Tags: regex, tcl

How to write a regexp in TCL that matches word and whitespaces. For example I have

```
aaaa    bbbb    cccc
```

and I want to match "aaaaa    ", "bbbb    ", "cccc    ".
And also please tell me what is the regex symbol for whitespace and non-whitespace. I can't find it anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My thought would be to just search for groupings of word characters:

```
set text {aaaa bbbb cccc}
regexp -all -inline {\S+} $text
> aaaa bbbb cccc
```

You can find the writeup for the Tcl regular expression syntax on the [re_syntax man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: specifically, `\S` is non-whitespace, more than just "word" characters.

Comment: And a note, the return value of the regexp command is a list of matched words, not the original string (although they happen to appear the same)

Comment: @glenn - while my mind thinks of "sequential non-whitespace" as "word" for the purposes of this question, that's a valid point. And good point on the return value. It didn't occur to me that it wasn't obvious that it returned 3 distinct values.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not *quite* sure exactly what you want, but here's an example:

```
set str "aaaa    bbbb    cccc       "
regexp {(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)} $str -> wordA wordB wordC
puts "The first is \"$wordA\", second \"$wordB\", and third \"$wordC\""
```

Which produces this output:

> The first is "aaaa", second "bbbb", and third "cccc"

Within the RE, `\S+` means a non-empty sequence of non-whitespace characters and `\s+` means a non-empty sequence of whitespace. I could have used `\w+` (“word” chars) and `\W+` (“non-word” chars) respectively. The parentheses in the RE surround capture groups; Tcl does not require REs to match the whole input string.

Comment: What would you do if the words were 1000? I mean you can't use regexp {(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)}, because this works ony for 3. So what solution can be applied for generic number?

Comment: @Narek: For a hundred words, I'd use RHSeeger's solution. For a few tends of thousands, I'd start asking whether I should be using a solution that handles things a bit at a time (and I might also think in terms of using a more complex parser). For a thousand, I'm not sure. :-)

Comment: Plus one. Life saver. Again.

Answer (score -1):

Regex symbol for whitespace is " ".  Like [a-z .] gives you a whitespace, as well as period and lowercase letters.

Comment: A space character will, to my knowledge, only match a space character. If you wanted to match all whitespace, you'd want to use the actual character class for such (\s or [[:space:]]).

Comment: space and whitespace are two different things. A space is just that -- a space. "whitespace" refers several characters that produce the space between words, typically including tabs and newlines.