# expect regex to search a complete line or text

Tags: regex, expect

my expect_output(buffer) is as below in multiple lines.

```
status QM1
QM(QM1)                                  Status(Running)
CPU:                                     0.02%
Memory:                                  106MB
Queue manager file system:               391MB used, 47.3GB allocated 
[1%]
HA role:                                 Primary
HA status:                               Normal
HA control:                              Enabled
HA preferred location:                   Here
mqa(mqcli)#
```

tried multiple regex options, but i keep getting 0, as no match.

`regexp /^.*\b(Running)\b.*$ $qmgrstat` similar, get the value of "HA Status".

What would be the correct Regex syntax.

Comment: referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067509/tcl-obtain-the-list-of-strings-separated-by-white-space-in-another-string-usin) but would not understand when we have multiple lines.

Comment: how do you try to do the regex? With `R`? With which options?

Comment: Note that expect (and the language it's built on, Tcl) has subtly different regex syntax: it's not PCRE. `\b` means a backspace character, not a word boundary: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture the HA status when the "QM" status is Running, you can do

```
if {[string match {*Status(Running)*} $qmgrstat]} {
    regexp {HA status:\s+(\S+)} $qmgrstat -> status
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand. Do you only want to match the value of `HA status`? If yes, then this regex would do that:

```
HA status:\W*(.*)
```

Comment: I would use `\s` instead of `\W` here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to get the whole output:

```
status[^\v]*\vQM[^\v]*\vCPU:[^\v]*\vMemory:[^\v]*\vQueue manager file system:[^\v]*\vHA role:[^\v]*\vHA status:[^\v]*\vHA control:[^\v]*\vHA preferred location:[^\v]*\vmqa[^\v]*#\v
```

if you want the complete line of text with the status use: `[^\v]*Status\([^\v]*`

To get the line with the HA status you can use: `HA status:[^\v]*`

Good luck!